# How to get slug value in getStaticProps to call api with parameter as slug

Tags: javascript, next.js

Page content:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
    
export default function Gunluk({ data }) {
    let router = useRouter()
    
    const { slug } = router.query;
    return slug;
}
```

And show on the page
60d6180ea9284106a4fd8441  (https://.../gunluk/60d6180ea9284106a4fd8441 id in URL)

So I can get the ID but I don't know how to pass it to API.

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/books-i-have`)
    const data = await res.json()
    
    if (!data) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }
    
    return {
        props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
}
```

Normally I use this but it didn't work in slug. I tried both other methods but failed (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).

**In short, how do you connect to the API from the Slug page?**

File directory:

```
    pages/
        gunluk/
            [...slug].js
            index.js
```

Comment: Context parameter is an object which contains params key which will be having your slug value, you can use that value for API call. I have posted an answer with the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the slug value in getStaticProps and use it to call api based on slug

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const idList = await fetchAllIds();
    const paths = [];
    idList.forEach((id) => { paths.push(`/gunluk/${id}`) })
    return { paths, fallback: true };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const { slug } = params;

    try {
        const data = await fetchGunluk(slug);
        return data ? { props: { data } } : { notFound: true };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return { notFound: true };
    }
}
```

Comment: **when i added it it returned**

Server Error
Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/gunluk/[...slug]'.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-getstaticpaths-value

Comment: Can you give an example for getStaticPaths()

Comment: I have added getStaticPath example for your reference

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation)

Answer (score 0):

i did this,
i have a file name `pages/course/[course_slug].js` in next js project

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const slug = router.query.course_slug;
  console.log(slug); //slug value
```

Comment: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'